# CDI interceptors and memcache

Tags: java, memcached, aop, cdi, interceptor

I was reading about interceptors and AOP, the way they can unclutter your code and externalize cross-cutting concerns into aspects. I instantly thought of CDI and the use of custom interceptors to access cache everytime one tries to access the database.
Is there any library that already implements this and supports memcache? I think calls to the entitymanager should be intercepted.

Comment: You can try [Solder](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Solder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, if you want to go that way, you need a pretty good reason to justify why Hibernate Cache / JBoss Cache (just guessing about your technology stack, but there are products / solution for almost all stacks) won't fit you needs?

You certainly don't want to reinvent the wheel in terms of developing your own query- or object cache, don't you?

Comment: Jan, thanks for your answer. I certainly do not want to reinvent the wheel and I haven't looked that much into Hibernate cache, I was familiar with memcache tho. I'll look into it asap and see if it fits my needs.

Comment: hibernate can use memcached as its cache, btw

Answer (score 1):

In general, using memcached to directly avoid DB requests is very difficult to get right and inefficient.  You really want to cache higher level concepts such as DAO -> DTO boundaries.

I've used AOP to inject cache invalidation and observer management code in java programs pretty successfully.  AOP allows me to think of a different set of reusability of different parts of my code.  It doesn't mean I don't have to design these aspects, but it frees me of limitations and prevents me from cutting and pasting, etc...

So my recommendation would be to design this access pattern such that you have to do a bunch of work at each of these boundaries, and then design cross cuts that inject that work at compile time.

Comment: Dustin, I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your suggestion, can you please elaborate? My initial idea was to intercept calls to the entitymanager, this interceptors would check whether the requested objects were already on the cache and if not proceed to query the database, else the objects would be retrieved from the cache, making the use of memcache totally transparent, Is this not a good idea?

Comment: Also, is it worth it to use interceptors? The whole point of using a cache is to avoid querying the database so you can achieve greater performance, but if decorators/interceptors add a noticable overhead then this gain is wasted.

Comment: The point of a cache is not to avoid querying the database.  The point of a cache is to memoize expensive work.  That's often related to the database, but usually not directly the results of a database query.  -- As far as whether your methodology is sound, it could definitely work, though invalidation would be harder.  See jan groth's response. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. This has helped me greatly.